# How To delete a table

Tags: android

How do i delete a whole table in android through code?

Comment: The actual table or the contents of a table?

Comment: The whole table including the content

Comment: Ok, well it'll depend on how you've created your table. Paste some code or describe what you have.

Comment: i have created it through code using db.execSQL

Comment: create table test ( " + BaseColumns._ID
       + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
       + USERNAME + " text, "
       + PASSWORD + " text not null);";
     Log.d("UsersData", "onCreate: " + sql2);
     db.execSQL(sql2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say just use a `DROP TABLE` query?

(I'm asuming you're talking about a database, and you're using the SQLite that's in Android, right? http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html )

an example as requested:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mydatabase.myTable
```

Comment: I have tried it, but doesnt seem to be working, maybe paste an example so i see how it is suppose to be used

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a database easily by writing a test case inheriting from AndroidTestCase (You don't have to but its an option), that way you will get access to Context, and call deleteDatabase("mydatabase.db") on it.